# Spring Boot and Cloud deployment

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, spring-boot, cloud, embedded-jetty

I'm currently developping a REST API with Spring boot. I want it to deploy on google cloud (compute engine).
I created a virtual linux machine, installed java 8 and put my spring boot application inside it.
It works fine but :
my application is a jar file (embedded Tomcat). I launched it with this :
java -jar myApp.jar
And it works fine.
But when I close the shell on google cloud, my application is no longer available.
I would like my app to be always available, without having to launch it every time I quit the shell. Is it possible ?

[image of cloud shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zad16.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing this is the same problem as this [Unix Thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-close-a-terminal-without-killing-the-command-running-in-it).

Fast answer is that your process is linked to the terminal. When you close it, the process is killed. If I quote [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148698) :

> What nohup does, on the other hand, is to effectively separate the
>   process from the terminal:
>
> - It closes standard input (the program will not be able to read any >input, even if it is run in the foreground. it is not halted, but will
>     receive an error code or EOF).
> - It redirects standard output and standard error to the file nohup.out, so the program won't fail for writing to standard output if
>     the terminal fails, so whatever the process writes is not lost.
> - It prevents the process from receiving a SIGHUP (thus the name).

So, try

```
nohup  java -jar myApp.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a virtual machine(google compute engine), you could use a script (bat in windows or sh in linux) to execute the java -jar command, but you can use too container engine and create a docker container with your app. configure a dockerfile and deploy. The container environment run your app automatically